# How do I stop Resharper from running my Specifications project when I Run All Tests from Solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper, resharper-5.1

I have a bunch of unit test projects for various other projects, and I have one Specifications project for the web application which runs Selenium 2 code via NUnit. This takes a much longer time to run than the rest of the tests.

I only want these specification tests to run when I run my build script, and when I explicitly run the project's tests, and not when I Run All Tests from Solution with Resharper.

**Is there any way to set up Resharper or NUnit to ignore a test project when I Run All Tests from Solution?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's not possible. You could filter and group your tests in the unit test session windows by project and then manually just run the groups you want. But this isn't a one click solution.

The only solution I can think about would be, to use two different unit test providers (e.g. MSTest and NUnit) and then disable the provider you're using in your specifications project in the ReSharper options.

Hope that helps.

Comment: From my research, this appears to be the case. :( Thanks though!